# Extract Instagram public API with limitation

Tags: instagram

I am using this URL to fetch Instagram hashtag post

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/catsndog/?__a=1

But when I check the returned results, the number of posts is uncontrollable. Is there anyways to limit the number of posts returned? Something like

```
?__a=1&limit=20
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is the javascript library that I found and it's gorgeous.

[Instafeed.js](http://instafeedjs.com/)

The most important thing about this is that it helps you to limit your instagram posts return by each load. Moreover, it can also supports paginating and "Load more" function. Really cool!

By the way, according to new policy by Instagram, you have to provide access token in order to get public content. And this is one of the service that can do it for you.

[Instagram access token generator](https://axentmedia.com/instagram-access-token/)